# Convert GMT/CST based string to Timestamp in java

Tags: java

I m trying to get time from one zone say IST OR ANY other time zone then convert it to GMT TIME zone string. But when I try to get timestamp from GMT based string time I get local timestamp value.  Any specific reason why so.

Comment: Post your code here

Answer (score 0):

Found this on web.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone fromTimeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
TimeZone toTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");

calendar.setTimeZone(fromTimeZone);
calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, fromTimeZone.getRawOffset() * -1);
if (fromTimeZone.inDaylightTime(calendar.getTime())) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, calendar.getTimeZone().getDSTSavings() * -1);
}

calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, toTimeZone.getRawOffset());
if (toTimeZone.inDaylightTime(calendar.getTime())) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, toTimeZone.getDSTSavings());
}

System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score -1):

"Any specific reason why so?"  Yes, because Java assumes that by default you want to "print out" (render) date values in the local timezone where the JVM is running.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Hello.TS_FORMAT);// TS_FORMAT = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssXX";
    Calendar cal = sdf.getCalendar();
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(UTC_TIME_ZONE));// UTC_TIME_ZONE = "GMT";
    sdf.setCalendar(cal);
    ...
}

@Test
public void testTimestampFormat03() {
    String inboundTimestampText = '20170322T170805-0700';// means inbound is in Pacific Time Zone (17:08:05 on 03/22)
    Date dt = sdf.parse(inboundTimestampText);
    String defaultFormat = dt.toString();// default locale is Central Time Zone (19:08:05 on 03/22)
    String actualFormat = sdf.format(dt);
    String expectedFormat = inboundTimestampText.replace('T17', 'T00');
    expectedFormat = expectedFormat.replace('0322', '0323');// expected Time Zone is UTC (00:08:05 on 03/23) 
    expectedFormat = expectedFormat.replace('-', 'Z');
    assertEquals(expectedFormat, actualFormat + '0700');
}
```

You have to specify the timezone you want the date value to "render" in.  Basically, you need to use "the same" formatter to print out the date `formatter.format(aDate)` that you used to read in the date string `formatter.parse(aDtaeString)`.